# error in calculating average in php code, output error

Tags: php, average

I have the following code in php that calculates the average scores. It works, but produces the wrong output (logic error)

**Code**

```
<p>Average Score</p>
                <?php
                $avg = 0;
                foreach ($scores as $score) {
                $avg += array_sum($score);
                }
                $avg /= count($scores);
                echo "<tr> <td>$avg</td></tr>"



                ?>
```

Desired output is 97.5 (because the scores are 100,100,100 and 90) but instead it is displaying: 100.25

**UPDATE - scores structure is important**

The earlier part of the code generating the scores is as below (to shed some light on the structure of scores -note I don't want an answer that just generates an array and averages it, I can do that, but rather want it fixed in this context)

```
<?php


                $a = new NewQuizScore;
                $scores = $a->getScores($_SESSION['username']);

                foreach ($scores as $score) {
                    echo ("<tr>");
                    echo ("<td>".$score[0]. "</td> ");
                    echo ("<td>".$score[1]. "</td> ");
                    echo ('<td><a href="certificate.php?name='.$score[0].'&score='.$score[1].'">Print Certificate</a></td>');
                    echo ("<td><a href=\"quiz-show.php?quiz=".$score[2]. "\">Take it again!</a></td> ");
                    echo ("</tr>");
                }



                ?>
```

Comment: try `$avg  += $score;` inside for loop

Comment: change $avg += array_sum($score); to $avg +=$score;

Comment: I tried that - as mentioned below and it just results in the page not loading

Comment: You might like to look at `array_column($scores,1)` as part of your solution with `array_sum()` and `count()`.  I think it will make cleaner looking code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you using `array_sum`?

`array_sum()` is a function to calculate the sum of values of an array. The value of `$score` is just a number, right?

Then change the below line

```
$avg += array_sum($score);
```

to

```
$avg += $score;
```

it will work

**Try the below code. It will work in your case**

```
$avg = 0;
foreach($scores as $score){
    $avg += $score[1];
}
$avg /= count($scores);

echo $avg;
```

Comment: I tried that and it resulted in the page not loading at all. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the structure of data you have in `$scores` array?

Comment: Please see update in my question with this information - thanks so much

Comment: Can you run `print_r($scores)` and provide to know the structure of `$scores` array? It is not able to identify from your question.

Comment: Call it just before `foreach ()` line. Use like `print_r($scores);die;` So it will terminate the process there and you can see the array value only.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$num = [100,100,100,90]; // marks as array 
$avg = array_sum($num) / count($num); // calculate avrage 

echo $avg; // output : 97.5

?>
```

**Update your code as shown below and try**

$scoreArr = []; // array for store score

```
    /* Your output array $scores */
    $scores = [
                [
                "1-Python Basics",
                "100",
                "01_PythonB"
                ],
                [
                "1-Python Output",
                "100",
                "02_Print_O"
                ],
                [
                "1-Python Basics",
                "90",
                "02_Print_O"
                ],
                [
                "1-Python Basics",
                "100",
                "03_Variabl"
                ],
            ];

    foreach($scores as $val) {

        $scoreArr[] = $val[1]; 
    }

    $avg = array_sum($scoreArr) / count($scoreArr); // calculate avrage 

    echo $avg;
    die;
```

Comment: I need to use the existing code for a reason as the scores are not in an array but generated elsewhere.

Comment: Hi Aman - I tried exactly what you have suggested, and it displays averagae: 0 !

Comment: can you post your print_r($scores)

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. Could you please explain? I put that line before the for loop, but no output?

Comment: $a = new NewQuizScore;
$scores = $a->getScores($_SESSION['username']);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($scores);

die;

Comment: @MissComputing display output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162891/discussion-between-misscomputing-and-aman-kumar).